# Site navigation using curtain.js with anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently making a site, which can be seen at www.TheOneCraft.co.uk .

It uses the curtain.js jquery plugin to animate the slide/pages as the user scrolls down, but i've been trying "and failing" to make the navigation bar do this.

I was wondering if anyone would know of a way to make clicking a link scroll down the page to the right point.

any and all help is appreciated,

thanks in advance

George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a description of this on the github page of the [project](https://github.com/Victa/curtain.js/#features)